# Rails: Uninitialized Constant inside Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a namespaced route and here's how I created the controller:

```
module A
  module B
    module Test
      class DummyController < ApplicationController

        def quantify_stocks
          something = Test::Dummy::Something.new(params)

          # more code here
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to access the class `Test::Dummy::Something` but it autoloads the constant Test with A and B (`A::B::Test`)?

The error I get is:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant A::B::Test::Dummy)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `::Test::Dummy::Something`

`Test` in this context will always refer to `A::B::Test` so you need to say explicitly that you need `Test` from the global namespace, which is exactly what `::Test` does

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for :)